# Mongoose validator: Get current document during update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using the following validation for email and username uniqueness

```
const unique = (field) => {
  return (value, callback) => {
    if (!value || value.length <= 0)
      callback(true)

    const query = Mongoose.model('User').where(field, new RegExp(`^${value}$`, 'i'))
    if(!this.isNew)
      query.where('_id').ne(this._id)

    query.count((err, n) => callback(n == 0))
  }
}
```

However, during update `this` is not set, so when updating an existing user with his/her own email/username, the update fails because on the where clause this._id is undefined.

I logged the value of this during validation and it's an empty object `{}`

Comment: why not using `unique : true` to ensure uniqueness

Comment: Because it's case sensitive uniqueness, which is ok for emails since they could be stored in lower case. But for username the "case?" must be preserved

Comment: For usernames, I'd store the name as lowercase, and if you need to present the case as the user typed it, add another field such as `displayName` that stores the case.  Do you really want two users in the system with the same username, differing only in case?